# Navigate to one page from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am making mobile app. And there i have 2 main pages. 1st is page with articles and second one is page with courses. In 1st page in the top i have made button that redirects to second page but it was not like i want to do. When i navigate i have something like this:
[image]

You can see that at the top i have arrow and name of the page. How can i make them together in one page? So i will have that : < Courses

```html
import Courses from './Courses'

<Button
onPress={() => {
   navigate('Courses')
}}
 title="More courses"
/>

  const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: {
        screen: Courses,
      },
      Details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
    }
  );

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <AppContainer />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try to look this url;
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 2 things `createBottomTabNavigator` and `createStackNavigator`

TabNvigator for the first level, and add a StackNavigator inside like this

- Home
- Courses

  - Listing
  - Detail
- Editor

```
const HomeNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
      },
      Courses: createStackNavigator(
        {
          CoursesListing: {
            screen: CoursesListingScreen
          },
          CoursesDetail: {
            screen: CoursesDetailScreen
          },
        },
      ),
      Details: {
        screen: DetailsScreen,
      },

    Home: screen: PrepareSessionsScreen
    ),
);

export default HomeNavigation;
```